Folder font not sent from src to dest
The folder with fonts from the working area is not moved to the public one.
Tell me, there are fonts in the folder, I don’t know why it doesn’t transfer them to the final project.
font: {
  src: `${pathSrc} /font/*.tff, otf, eot, otc, ttc, woff, woff2, svg`,
  watch: `${pathSrc}/font/**/*.tff, otf, eot, otc, ttc, woff, woff2, svg`,
  dest: `${pathDest}/font`,
},

export default () => {
return gulp
    .src(path.font.src)
    .pipe(
plumber({
errorHandler: notify.onError((error) => ({
title: "FONT",
message: error.message,
        })),
      })
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.font.dest));
};


You have a space in ${pathSrc} /font....  Is that intended?
